# Python's `range` function with 3 parameters

Tags: python, function, range

I understand that the following line will give the given result:

```
for in range(5):
   print(i)
```

0
1
2
3
4

But I don't understand how if adding 3 separate parameters the result is confusing. How is this returning these particular results? (4 6 and 8) ????

```
for i in range(4, 10, 2):
 print(i)
```

4
6
8

Comment: the last argument is the step so obviously using a step of 2 gives you 4,6,8

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the docs: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#the-range-function are clear

Answer (score 28):

Starts at 4, then increments by 2, to end at 8 because `10 < 10` is false. So `4 6 8`

Comment: OK - got it. Sorry I didn't exhaust my research on that one - thanks again.

Answer (score 8):

```
for i in range(4, 10, 2):
 print(i)
```

in the above code, range has 3 parameters :

1. Start of Range (inclusive)
2. End of Range (Exclusive)
3. Incremental value

> For more clarity refer for the java representation of above
> python code:
>
> ```
> for (int i=4; i<10; i+=2){
>     System.out.println(i)
> }
> ```

Answer (score 2):

range(start_pos,  end_pos,  increment)

Comment: Some sentence explaining the answer would be appreciated.

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis okay thanks for the note i will explain more in future